# Color and empty cell or add text to an empty cell via CSS

Tags: css

I am working on an accessibility preview that uses css to highlight potential problems on a page. I am currently trying to find a way using css only, to somehow highlight an empty cell in a table or add text to it that read something like "This is an empty cell and can cause accessibility issues.

I know of the empty cell option:

```
table {
  empty-cells: show;
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to then format those empty cells with something that makes them stand out. Not even sure if it is possible via CSS but I figured I would check with brains smarter than mine as I continue to try and figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at the [`:empty` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty).

```css
table td:empty {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>OK</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>OK</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you duplicated my answer ... (not really !)

Comment: @frederic I guess this is the kind of question that gets a clear answer, and the correct answers all look the same ;)

Comment: @frederic: I guess you are wrong. You have answered 5 minutes ago while Runar Berg has answered 9 minutes w.r.t.current time :) So your claim is baseless I guess :) So Runar is 4 minutes ahead of you in general !!! :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather This happens quite often really that two users are answering at the same time. Usually the answers are quite different, but this time there is an obvious way to answer the question so it looks like the answers are copying each other. This time I just happened to type faster and post first.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! This really helps a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`:empty` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty). Example:

```css
table {
  empty-cells: show;
}
td:empty {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Cell with content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell with content</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I appreciate the help!

Comment: @BillyWoody please accept my answer using the grey checkmark on the left of my answer if it is possible (i do not know, the question has been closed)

Comment: It was closed as a duplicate, but I’m not sure it was the right choice. There is a subtle difference in these questions. The linked question is asking the whitespace behavior of the `:empty` selector (as is clear if you read the accepted answer), while this question is asking for the existence of it.

Comment: I think this question should be reopened @RúnarBerg, only i dont have enough reputation to vote for that :(